# Free software for CSR Bluetooth usb dongle on Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, bluetooth, device-driver

I got a usb `CSR bluetooth dongle` that has basic file transfer capabilities on windows 7. I cannot connect to other bluetooth headsets from this dongle. The hardware profiles like `A2DP`, `HSP` do not have drivers on Windows 7.

The device when connected to windows 10 based pc, works flawlessly with bluetooth headsets.

So, Is there any software on Windows 7, that is free and has A2DP , HSP bluetooth drivers ? I have tried `IVT Bluesoleil` but it is only evaluation copy that limits data.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no actualy free Bluetooth drivers. Usualy your dongle should include drivers. If it does not try any Toshiba. Probably it has your dongle's PID/VID and will work in full mode (not in 30 day trial).

The other possible solution is WidComm. On Win 7 it works as a MS drivers extention and adds support for HFP and other unsupported by default profiles.

Comment: Could you include links to WidComm or Toshiba?